# Why won't the loop function as intended? Details below:

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, break

I have asked a similar question before, but here's a slightly different problem I'm encountering after fixing some previous issues:

There are two txt files that are structured similarly into columns. File 1 has the following columns: tagname1, aapos, synonymous; and file 2 has the following: tagname2, aapos1, aapos2. What I want to do is compare every single tagname1 in file 1 to every single tagname2 in file 2 and see if they match. For every single match, I want the program to then check if the aapos value corresponding to that specific tagname1 falls betweeen aapos1 and aapos2, as stated by my second if statement. If after going through all of file 2, it is unable to find a match for aapos, ONLY then do I want to execute the following if statements and check if synonymous in file 1 is equal to 0 or 1 and add 1 to syn2 or nonsyn2, depending on the case. The same applies if for a specific tagname1, the program goes through the entire list of tagname2 in file 2, and is unable to find a match.

However, according to my code, the program only runs once and I get a value of 1 for snps and a value of one for nonsyn2. I'm not sure why this is the case.

for x in range(1,15):

```
    flag = 0
    snps = 0 
    for b in range (1,15):

        if tagname1[x]== tagname2[b]:
            flag = 1 

            if int(aapos1[b]) <= int(aapos[x])<= int(aapos2[b]): 

                snps = snps + 1


    if snps == 0: 
        if int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 

            nonsyn2 = nonsyn2 + 1

        elif int(synonymous[x]) == 1: 

            syn2 = syn2 + 1      

    elif flag == 0:  

        if int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 

            nonsyn2 = nonsyn2 + 1

        elif int(synonymous[x]) == 1: 

            syn2 = syn2 + 1
```

Comment: Please format your code consistently. It's hard to read as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you mean to break in the lower if statements?

eg:

```
    if int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 

        nonsyn2 = nonsyn2 + 1
        break
```

These are within the first for loop (for x in range(1,15):) so if one of these conditions is met you will be dropped out of the loop.

If this happens on your first loop, it might be why you only see it run once.

I'm not entirely sure I understand what your trying to do, but the keyword 'continue' might be what you want. It will make the program go to the next iteration of your loop.

Comment: You may also need to reset `snps` at the beginning of the loop, as you do `flag` - I'm not sure if that's supposed to accumulate for the different entries in your first file or not. Right now it will.

Comment: I think you're both correct. I have made the following changes, but there is still another problem. The first match for both the criteria set by the first two if statements is at value number 12. Therefore, when I set the range to anything below 12, I will get values for nonsyn2 and syn2 that will add up to the upper limit of my range, as intended/expected. However, as soon as I increase my range to 12 or 13, at which point it does find a match, the total sum of the numbers I get for syn2 and nonsyn2, plus the match it found, doesn't add up to the upper limit of my range.

Comment: Did you try removing all the break and continue keywords. now I look again I don't think either are needed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by continue keywords, but I did remove all the breaks.

Comment: Ok cool - I think you have code that I can't see, but a quick way of troubleshooting would be to put some print statements in places where you would like to see whats going on. try adding 'print x , nosyn2 , syn2' after the bottom ifs. It might show how the loop is running for you and hint where to fix

Comment: One last thing though, for some reason, the if statement (flag == 0) executes even if tagname1 is not equal to tagname2. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Well, flag will only be 1 if there is a match inside your 'inner' loop ( if tagname1[x]== tagname2[b] ) otherwise its still the 0 set at the top of each loop

Comment: For some reason, even if there is a match, it still executes either snp == 0 if statement or the flag == 0 if statement. It should only execute either of those if statements if there is a mismatch, depending on whether the mismatch is in the outer loop or inner loop.

Comment: well for snp to be not equal to zero, it first needs to match tagname1[x]== tagname2[b]: THEN it needs to match if int(aapos1[b]) <= int(aapos[x])<= int(aapos2[b]):     Maybe you need both these if's at the same indentation / level. At the moment the second if depends on the first.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's how it should be. But the problem is that even if the first two if statements are satisfied, the 3rd if statement (snp == 0) still tends to be executed.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. If you really think its the case id put 'print x , " SNP NOW " , snps' directly after snps = snps + 1  then something like 'print x , " SNP IS " , snps' right before the if. That way you will be able to match the update of snps and see its value directly before the if statement.